# How to get email notifications when questions are asked about your favorite software or favorite topic

Tags: discussion, faq

My friend Peter Nagy, a developer of the MRCC software, asked me how to get email notifications when people ask questions with the [mrcc](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mrcc) tag.

Surprisingly I could not remember how I did it years ago when I started following certain tags on other Stack Exchanges, and I couldn't find the answer easily on Meta Stack Exchange, for example, the accepted answer here: [Email notifications for new questions matching specific tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25224/email-notifications-for-new-questions-matching-specific-tags), says you can't get emails, only RSS feeds, which is wrong/out-of-date. The accepted answer here: [Getting email notifications when comments or answers are posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142192/391772), says you can get emails only for responses to your own questions and answers, which is also wrong or out-of-date.

**So how is it done?**

Answer (score 8):

You can do the following:

Go here: https://stackexchange.com/filters and fill out the form:

[image]

In this example I'm asking to get an email whenever a question with the [basis-sets](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basis-sets) tag is given on this site (but if more than one question with that tag is asked in a 15 minute time span, I will get a single email containing all of the questions that were asked in that 15 minute period).

If it doesn't work in your browser, perhaps you can let me know in the comments and I will try to help you.

**You might have to change "materials" to "matter" (or might not, since it might not have updated yet).**

Comment: It might help to accept this answer just to bump this up and so that users can see at a glance that there is a solution.

Comment: @Tyberius I thought it looks a bit bad to accept one's own answer. This "answer" was originally in the question, but Catija suggested in the comments to write an answer. I'm skeptical about how many people actually come and look here for answers to this particular question (so I'm not sure how much bumping up, and adding green to the answer icon, will help), but I've sent this Q/A thread to people when informing them that it's possible to subscribe to tags (in that case they don't need to see that an answer is accepted, since they're being directed immediately to the answer).